# Dynamic select expression in function

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to write a function that will convert this data frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(obj=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 S1=rep(c("a","b"),length.out=10),PR1=rep(c(3,7),length.out=10),
                 S2=rep(c("c","d"),length.out=10),PR2=rep(c(7,3),length.out=10))

   obj S1 PR1 S2 PR2
1    1  a   3  c   7
2    1  b   7  d   3
3    2  a   3  c   7
4    2  b   7  d   3
5    3  a   3  c   7
6    3  b   7  d   3
7    3  a   3  c   7
8    4  b   7  d   3
9    4  a   3  c   7
10   4  b   7  d   3
```

In to this data frame

```
df %>% {bind_rows(select(., obj, S = S1, PR = PR1),
              select(., obj, S = S2, PR = PR2))}
   obj S PR
1    1 a  3
2    1 b  7
3    2 a  3
4    2 b  7
5    3 a  3
6    3 b  7
7    3 a  3
8    4 b  7
9    4 a  3
10   4 b  7
11   1 c  7
12   1 d  3
13   2 c  7
14   2 d  3
15   3 c  7
16   3 d  3
17   3 c  7
18   4 d  3
19   4 c  7
20   4 d  3
```

But I would like the function to be able to work with any number of columns. So it would also work if I had S1, S2, S3, S4 or if there was an additional category ie DS1, DS2. Ideally the function would take as arguments the patterns that determine which columns are stacked on top of each other, the number of sets of each column, the names of the output columns and the names of any variables that should also be kept.

This is my attempt at this function:

```
stack_col <- function(df, patterns, nums, cnames, keep){
  keep <- enquo(keep)
  build_exp <- function(x){
   paste0("!!sym(cnames[[", x, "]]) := paste0(patterns[[", x, "]],num)") %>% 
      parse_expr()
  }
  exps <- map(1:length(patterns), ~expr(!!build_exp(.)))

  sel_fun <- function(num){
    df %>% select(!!keep, 
                  !!!exps)
  }
  map(nums, sel_fun) %>% bind_rows()
}
```

I can get the `sel_fun` part to work for a fixed number of patterns like this

```
patterns <- c("S", "PR")
cnames <- c("Species", "PR")
keep <- quo(obj)
sel_fun <- function(num){
df %>% select(!!keep,
!!sym(cnames[[1]]) := paste0(patterns[[1]], num),
!!sym(cnames[[2]]) := paste0(patterns[[2]], num))
}
sel_fun(1)
```

But the dynamic version that I have tried does not work and gives this error:

```
Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument
```

Comment: Looks like it is easier with `melt` from `data.table` `melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^S\\d+", "^PR\\d+"), value.name = c("S", "PR"))[, variable := NULL][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function to get the expected output.  Loop through the 'patterns' and the corresponding new column names ('cnames') using `map2`, `gather` into 'long' format, `rename` the 'val' column to the 'cnames' passed into the function, bind the columns (`bind_cols`) and `select` the columns of interest

```
stack_col <- function(dat, pat, cname, keep) {

    purrr::map2(pat, cname, ~ 
                    dat %>%
                       dplyr::select(keep, matches(.x)) %>%
                       tidyr::gather(key, val, matches(.x)) %>%
                       dplyr::select(-key) %>%
                       dplyr::rename(!! .y := val)) %>%
       dplyr::bind_cols(.) %>%
       dplyr::select(keep, cname) 



}

stack_col(df, patterns, cnames, 1)
#    obj Species PR
#1    1       a  3
#2    1       b  7
#3    2       a  3
#4    2       b  7
#5    3       a  3
#6    3       b  7
#7    3       a  3
#8    4       b  7
#9    4       a  3
#10   4       b  7
#11   1       c  7
#12   1       d  3
#13   2       c  7
#14   2       d  3
#15   3       c  7
#16   3       d  3
#17   3       c  7
#18   4       d  3
#19   4       c  7
#20   4       d  3
```

---

Also, multiple patterns reshaping can be done with `data.table::melt`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^S\\d+", "^PR\\d+"), 
          value.name = c("Species", "PR"))[, variable := NULL][]
```

Comment: This is great! I added a `keep <- enquo(keep)` and `!!` in front of each use of keep so that I can pass a column name instead of number or multiple columns like `obj:x`. The `data.table` version seems the best though. I think I will just wrap it in a function so I don't have to remember the syntax in the future since I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @see24  yes, I wasn't sure whether you need a numeric index or name

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem, although it does not fix your function:

The idea is to use `gather` and `spread` on the columns which starts with the specific pattern. Therefore I create a regex which matches the column names and then first gather all of them, extract the group and the rename the groups with the cnames. Finally spread takes separates the new columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

patterns <- c("S", "PR")
cnames <- c("Species", "PR")
names(cnames) <- patterns 
complete_pattern <- str_c("^", str_c(patterns, collapse = "|^"))

df %>% 
  mutate(rownumber = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(new_variable, value, matches(complete_pattern)) %>% 
  mutate(group = str_extract(new_variable, complete_pattern), 
         group = str_replace_all(group, cnames),
         group_number = str_extract(new_variable, "\\d+")) %>% 
  select(-new_variable) %>% 
  spread(group, value)

#    obj rownumber group_number PR Species
# 1    1         1            1  3       a
# 2    1         1            2  7       c
# 3    1         2            1  7       b
# 4    1         2            2  3       d
# 5    2         3            1  3       a
# 6    2         3            2  7       c
# 7    2         4            1  7       b
# 8    2         4            2  3       d
# 9    3         5            1  3       a
# 10   3         5            2  7       c
# 11   3         6            1  7       b
# 12   3         6            2  3       d
# 13   3         7            1  3       a
# 14   3         7            2  7       c
# 15   4         8            1  7       b
# 16   4         8            2  3       d
# 17   4         9            1  3       a
# 18   4         9            2  7       c
# 19   4        10            1  7       b
# 20   4        10            2  3       d
```